# SignalR for sending message to WPF client to update data from mariaDB

Tags: c#, .net, mariadb

Currently working in Net 6. I have a mariaDB for storing data. I will have multiple clients accessing the same db. When one client adds/removes/updates a record, I want all the clients to refresh their data to show the changes. I could poll the database, but I wanted to try it differently.

I am using WebAPI to get and put data into the sql server, and I was thinking of using SignalR to send a message to the connected clients to update their tables.

My question, should I be looking into something else, or can SignalR be used for this function? All the tutorials that I have found use SignalR for a chat program, and I'm not going that route.